# Load Modal when EJS Page Loads

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, ejs

I want to load a modal when my EJS page loads. Is that possible and if yes, then how?

I am using Node.js and express js for my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your modal inside a jQuery load event on the head section of your EJS page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', () => $('#yourModal').modal('show'));
</script>
```